# Implementation of DHCP protocol?

Tags: networking, internet

I am taking a networking course, and am trying to understand protocols such as tcp/ip, DHCP etc.

I did a google search for the source-code for TCP/IP protocol, and learnt that it resides in the kernel of the Operating System; Basically, TCP/IP implementation is the responsibility of the kernel of the OS.

I am trying to do the same for the DHCP protocol, but have not had much luck.

Can somebody tell me where does the source-code(implementation) of DHCP live?

Comment: Which DHCP implementation are you talking about? ISC DHCPd, ISC Kea, dhclient, udhcpd, dnsmasq, the one built into Windows, the one built into macOS, …? There's something like 4 different DHCP libraries for Python alone, another half dozen for Perl, multiple for Ruby, dozens for C, and so on. Note: it is very unlikely that Microsoft will give you access to the source code. They only give the source code to government agencies or Operating Systems researchers.

Comment: @JörgWMittag does DHCP implementation reside in the kernel of the OS?

Comment: "I did a google search for the source-code for TCP/IP protocol, and learnt that it resides in the kernel of the Operating System" – That depends on the OS. It is quite common for embedded devices to implement networking in user space. Also, for microkernel and exokernel OSs, networking would be in user space.

Comment: "does DHCP implementation reside in the kernel of the OS" – The author of the OS can implement DHCP however they want. In Linux, it is in user space, but that doesn't mean there can't be an OS where it is in the kernel.

Comment: @JörgWMittag can you explain your comment "embedded devices to implement networking"? I don't have much background in hardware.

Comment: @Max TCP is *usually* in the kernel, but it doesn't have to be. There are hardware accelerators which do things like fragment reassembly for you, and there are systems which just pass a stream of packets to user space. Either of these may be faster under certain circumstances.

Comment: Similarly, DCHP *may or may not* be in the kernel. On Linux it is not. Windows hides it away in the operating system somewhere.

Comment: Anyway, among all this the most important thing to remember is "There is no one single implementation of DHCP" - you have to look at the standards.

Comment: @pjc50 more broadly "There is no one single implementation of a protocol" is often true

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no one single implementation of DHCP, there are several, but the most common one is the Internet Software Consortium one, which is [on github](https://github.com/isc-projects/dhcp/blob/master/client/dhclient.c).

However, reading the source is not the best way to understand internet protocols. Reading the [RFCs](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2131) is, since that is independent of implementation details. In addition to RFC 2131, you should at least skim the ones suggested at the side: RFC 4361, RFC 5494, RFC 6842, RFC 3396. Those will describe extensions to the original protocol.